# How to change the highlighting color for matching parentheses / double quotes in VS2013 for VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

How can I change the highlighting color for matching parentheses / double quotes in Visual Studio 2013 (language VB.NET)?

In Tools -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Display Items, I tried changing (and ran over all other options but can't seem to find a suiting one):

- the colors for **Brace Matching (Highlight)**
- the colors for **Brace Matching (Rectangle)**

It annoys me I can't see the characters when they are highlighted.
[image: Example of parentheses with ToString method:]

**Edit:** "Brace Matching (Highlight)" -> Item Background, greyed out, changing the foreground color on this option doesn't seem to change anything either:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Environment -> Fonts and Color -> Brace Matching and change the "Item Background"

With the dark theme Maroon works well.

Comment: With "Brace matching (Highlight)", which seems to be the option I need, "Item Background" is greyed out. It's only possible to change the foreground color.
The opposite for "Brace Matching (Rectangle)", foreground greyed out, background can be changed.
Edit: changed the foreground color for  "Brace matching (Highlight)", didn't make a change.

Comment: What about changing the background color for "Brace Matching(Rectangle)"?

Comment: I did that too. Still the same, no change in parentheses font or highlight color.